# Не удается русифицировать календарь datapicker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, календарь

Есть блок с возможностью выбора даты и времени. 
Хочу сделать так, чтобы он выглядел согласно картинке, но у меня возникает проблема с русификацией календаря при использовании `datapicker bootstrap`, хотя указываю в настройках `locale: 'ru'` согласно [документации](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/).

В чем может быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD MMMM',
    locale: 'ru',
    daysMin: ["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"],
    months: ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"]
  });
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'mm'
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  border-right: none;
}

.input-group-text {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Дата</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Время</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ - нужно подгружать библиотеку `moment-with-locales.min.js` вместо `moment.min.js`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD MMMM',
    locale: 'ru'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH'
  });
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'mm'
  });
});
```

```css
.input-group .form-control {
  border-right: none;
}

.input-group .input-group-text {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.datetimepicker-input {
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Дата</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Время</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```